# "Invalid universal id" error with Domino Access Service API

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to access Domino data using Domino Access Service (DAS) API. I have enabled Data service in Domino server and also allowed "Views and Documents" in Domino Data Service property of the database. I am sending https request to this url - `https://{{Server}}/{{Database}}/api/data/documents/unid/{{UNID}}`. But I am getting error

> Invalid universal id

[image: Invalid universal id error]

I tried with different databases and same error is coming.

Comment: Are you sending a valid UNID (32 characters)? and are you sure that a document with that UNID exists in the database?

Comment: What, exactly, is the value you are sending for the UNID? How did you get that value? Show your code!

Comment: I am just sending https request from browser right now and I am getting UNID from Notes Document properties..they are like these "852577D900812B5685257651008252BB"

Comment: Does the web user have access to that document? The data service returns a 404 error if the user has access to the database but can't access the requested document. This can occur for a logged-in user if the document has Readers fields excluding that user, or for an anonymous user with the "read public documents" privilege if the document isn't public.